# How to append more items to an existing vector contained in the value field of a std::map?

Tags: c++11, stdvector, stdmap, stdstring

I have a `std::vector<std::string>>`. Following is my full program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <map>
 
int main() {
    std::cout << " -- Beginining of program -- " << std::endl;
    
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> my_map_2;
    std::vector<std::string> s = {"a", "b", "c"};
    my_map_2.insert(std::make_pair("key1", s));
    std::vector<std::string> s2 = {"d", "e", "f"};
    my_map_2.insert(std::make_pair("key1", s2));

    for(auto const &map_item: my_map_2) {
        std::cout << map_item.first << " " << map_item.second[0] << std::endl;
        std::cout << map_item.first << " " << map_item.second[1] << std::endl;
        std::cout << map_item.first << " " << map_item.second[2] << std::endl;
        std::cout << map_item.first << " " << map_item.second[3] << std::endl;
        std::cout << map_item.first << " " << map_item.second[4] << std::endl;
        std::cout << map_item.first << " " << map_item.second[5] << std::endl;
    }
    
    std::cout << " -- End of program -- " << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Problem:**
I don't see the items of `s2` when I print values of `my_map_2`. I see them only if I add `s2` with a new key! If I do `my_map_2.insert(std::make_pair("key2", s2))` instead of `my_map_2.insert(std::make_pair("key1", s2))`, I do see the items.

**Question:**
So, my question is, *how to I append* more items to the vector pointed to by `key1` of `my_map_2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get iterator to `key1`, and just pushs back new items to existing vector:

```
std::vector<std::string> s2 = {"d", "e", "f"};
auto it = my_map_2.find("key1");
if (it != my_map_2.end())
    std::move(s2.begin(), s2.end(), std::back_inserter(it->second));
else 
    my_map_2.insert(std::make_pair("key1",std::move(s2)));
```

To see: d,e,f you have to access 3,4 and 5 indices of vector. (You want to append new items, or just override existed items for given key?)

Comment: I want to append, not override

Comment: You have a `if` and probably in the else part, it should create the new new and simply add vector I guess

Comment: in else part could be: `my_map_2.insert(std::make_pair("key1",std::move(s2)));`

Comment: The whole `if ... else` could be `std::copy(s2.begin(), s2.end(), std::back_inserter(my_map_2["key1"]));`

Comment: Aha. It automatically creates a new entry if required then? Nice!

Answer (score 3):

The below fails because the key is already taken:

```
std::vector<std::string> s2 = {"d", "e", "f"};
my_map_2.insert(std::make_pair("key1", s2));    // fails
```

To append to the mapped vector, you could do like this:

```
auto& vec = my_map_2["key1"];    // get reference to the existing vector
vec.insert(vec.end(), s2.begin(), s2.end()); // append to it
```

To view the keys and all the values in the vector you could change your loop to this:

```
for(auto const&[key, value]: my_map_2) {
    for(const std::string& str : value) {
        std::cout << key << ' ' << str << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`my_map_2["key1"]` is always a valid vector. You can `insert` into it directly

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <map>
 
int main() {
    std::cout << " -- Beginining of program -- " << std::endl;
    
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> my_map_2;
    std::vector<std::string> s = {"a", "b", "c"};
    my_map_2["key1"].insert(my_map_2["key1"].end(), s.begin(), s.end());
    std::vector<std::string> s2 = {"d", "e", "f"};
    my_map_2["key1"].insert(my_map_2["key1"].end(), s2.begin(), s2.end());

    for(auto const &map_item: my_map_2) {
        for(auto const &value: map_item.second) {
            std::cout << map_item.first << " " << value << std::endl;
        }
    }
    
    std::cout << " -- End of program -- " << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```